# Edit control doesn't work correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

I started to learning winapi c++ today. And i wrote this simple program that have to change window name to the name that i write in text box:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void AddMenu(HWND);
void AddControl(HWND);


HWND hEdit;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrewInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"class";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"class", L"Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case 1:
            MessageBeep(MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION); break;
        case 2:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd); break;
        case 3:
            wchar_t text[100];
            GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);
            SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
            break;
        }
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenu(hWnd);
        AddControl(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}

void AddMenu(HWND hWnd)
{
    HMENU hMenu;
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU file;
    file = CreateMenu();
    HMENU Sub;
    Sub = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)file, "File");

    AppendMenu(file, MF_STRING, 1, "Open");
    AppendMenu(file, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)Sub, "Sub");

    AppendMenu(file, MF_STRING, 2, "Exit");

    AppendMenu(Sub, MF_STRING, 3, "Change");

    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);

}

void AddControl(HWND hWnd)
{
    CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Enter text: ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER, 200, 100, 100, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    hEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"...", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 200, 152, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

}
```

By default in text box i have `...`. So i run my program, starting to type `hello world` for expample but nothing changes. I highlited my 3 dots that had to change and boom, my text appeared. I go to the menu choose File -> Sub -> Change and my window name changes to 3 dots `...`.
BUT! If i delete these: `| ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL` then text box working correctly but menu doesnt show up in my window.

I found that i have to do smth with `EN_CHANGE` but idk what. I tried to change `WM_COMMAND` to `EN_CHANGE` and my textbox worked correctly, but other menu buttons didnt work at all...

Comment: I hope you're not using a window class named literally `"class"`.  These things should be unique.

Comment: i dont i guess? atleast in my code i didnt write any classes, afaik winapi already has classes for static and edit controls. correct me if im wrong. i just started to learn this

Comment: You did create a window class, for your parent window.  Using the standard window classes for the two child windows is fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Window class names need to be unique. However, for a class that doesn't have the `CS_GLOBALCLASS` style, the scope is the *module*. Since you usually have full control over your module, using a generic class name like `L"class"` is not much to worry about.

Comment: @IInspectable: And then you'd better not statically link with any libraries, because they'll become part of your module and share the namespace.  Best to use a unique name.

Comment: ah, ok, now i get it where i define `"class"`. but still, i dont understand how to test notification code....

Comment: @BenVoigt: If you statically link with a library that registers window classes, then surely those class names are part of the public interface, and documented. But really, I was commenting on your first statement, that *"window class name[s] [...] should be unique"*. As written, it reads like they would need to be globally unique, which is not the case. They need to be unique per module, or process (if registered as `CS_GLOBALCLASS`). If you talk about uniqueness constraints, you also need to include the scope.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well I do mean they *should* be globally unique, that's just good style.  Pedantically it's possible to have basic `CreateWindow` functionality succeed with only local uniqueness, but many operations such as `FindWindow` rely on global uniqueness. So "Mandatory: local uniqueness" but "Recommended: global uniqueness"

Comment: @BenVoigt: Global uniqueness is stricter than local uniqueness (which is required by the API). If there is a reason for your window class instances to be uniquely identifiable, then there is nothing wrong with choosing a globally unique class identifier. But global uniqueness is not the requirement imposed by the API. Details, as always, at Raymond Chen's blog: [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873)

Comment: @IInspectable: I just gave you an example of an API that assumes global uniqueness, another is `GetClassName`.  Some APIs will work under conditions of local uniqueness, others will break.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `GetClassName` will not break in case a window class name is not globally unique. Likewise, `FindWindow` does not require unique window class names. Even in case of a unique class name, there may be more than one instance of that window class, and you still have to implement additional logic to identify the instance you are looking for.

Comment: @IInspectable: The APIs still "succeed", but the results either (for `GetClassName`) only correctly identify the window class, if it is unique (does `GWLP_INSTANCE` return the module of the window class?) or (for `FindWindow`) mix together windows from multiple classes.  Neither is accomplishing what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

Your failure is caused by handling all the edit control notifications the same way.  You need to test the notification code (found in `HIWORD(wParam)`) to see whether it is `EN_CHANGE`, and let notifications you aren't handling pass through to `DefWindowProc`.

You also have an even bigger bug in that you reach the closing brace of a function with a non-`void` return type.  You need to always return something; when you aren't calling `DefWindowProc` the system still expects a return value.  The reason things start working when you change `WM_COMMAND` to `EN_CHANGE` is not because you are handling `EN_CHANGE`, it is because you no longer have incorrect handling of `WM_COMMAND`, and instead let the `DefWindowProc` take them.

The fall-through from `WM_COMMAND` into `WM_CREATE` isn't helping things either.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (HIWORD(wParam)) /* command kind */
        {
        case 0: // menus
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) /* child ID */
            {
            case 1:
                MessageBeep(MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION);
                return 0;
            case 2:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                return 0;
            case 3:
                wchar_t text[100];
                GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);
                SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenu(hWnd);
        AddControl(hWnd);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    // break actions also reach here
    return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```